# close modal after submit of form on redirect to same page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, modal-dialog

I have a form inside a modal that automatically opens on load.  the form submits the time to a database when it is activated which starts a timer to evaluate how long it takes a participant to complete a task on the page.  The page redirects to itself when the submit button is clicked as the events to be measured are on the opening screen. However when the page is reloaded the modal opens once again.  How would I stop the modal from opening again on the submit of the form and reloading of the page?   I have everything working but this part. I am using basic jquery. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1):

Add destination url for your link. Get more help from below urls:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66707/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-after-submitting-the-ctools-modal-form/108040#108040

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29157/redirect-form-out-of-modal-window-after-submit/108039#108039

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to the same page with an added query string value that stops the modal from being displayed.

Comment: Like your solution.  How would the query string for stopping a modal be written?

Comment: Use Jquery to check for parameters in the URL. If it finds a particular parameter it either fires the function to show the modal or not display it.